# Problems with Fancytree drag-and-drop

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, fancytree

I am using Fancytree with generally good results. However, I have found a problem with DND. If preventNonNodes is set to true, then my dragEnter function routine is never called. There is a line of code that reads "if (dndOpts.preventNonNodes && !nodeData)". In practice, noneData is always undefined. If preventNonNodes is true, then the dragEnter() routine is never called? What am I doing wrong here. Should this question be posted over on GitHub?

Below is some code that works. The dragEnter routine is invoked.

```
    /* Provide some options and routines for drag-and-drop */
    dnd5: {
      /* Expand nodes after n milliseconds of hovering - default */
      autoExpandMS: 1500,      
      /* Absolute position offset for .fancytree-drop-marker - default */
      /* Relative to ..fancytree-title (icon/img near a node accepting drop) */
      dropMarkerOffsetX: -24,  
      /* Additional offset for drop-marker with hitMode = "before"/"after" - default*/
      dropMarkerInsertOffsetX: -16, 
      /* true: Drag multiple (i.e. selected) nodes - default is false*/
      multiSource: false,                
      /* Prevent dropping nodes from different Fancytrees - default is false */
      preventForeignNodes: true,   
      /* Prevent dropping items other than Fancytree nodes - default is false */
      preventNonNodes: false,       
      /* Prevent dropping nodes on own descendants - default */
      preventRecursiveMoves: true,  
      /* Prevent dropping nodes 'before self', etc. - default */
      preventVoidMoves: true,     
      /* Enable auto-scrolling while dragging - default */
      scroll: true,        
      /* Active top/bottom margin in pixel - default */
      scrollSensitivity: 20,        
      /* Pixels per event - default */
      scrollSpeed: 5,               
      /* Events (drag support) */
      dragStart: function (node, data) {
        console.log('dragStart');
        return true;
      },
      dragDrag: function (node, data) {
        console.log('dragDrag');
      }, 
      dragEnd: function (node, data) {
        console.log('dragEnd');
      },         
      /* Events (drop support) */
      dragEnter: function (node, data) {
        console.log('dragEnter');
        return true;
      },      
      dragOver: function (node, data) {
        console.log('dragOver');
      },     
      dragExpand: function (node, data) {
        console.log('dragExpand');
        return true;
      },      
      dragDrop: function (node, data) {
        console.log('dragDrop');
      },
      dragLeave: function (node, data) {
        console.log('dragLeave');
      }
    },
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Maybe you found a bug: you should open an issue on the project page.

Comment: mar10, I is possible that I found a bug. It is also very possible that my code has a bug (or bugs). I will open an issue over on Github.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was due to a bug that was [fixed here](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/issues/928) for release 2.30.2